# Problems with the installation of VirtualBox on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: installation, virtualbox, ubuntu-20.04

just so you know I'm pretty new at Linux.

I just made the jump from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS because I thought there wouldn't be a problem with VirtualBox.
When the upgrade was finished I noticed VirtualBox was gone, I tried to install it following the instruction on the official website and [other](https://linuxconcept.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux/) [sites](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-20-04/).

I don't know what you guys exactly need to help me solve the problem so here's some informations :

Here's what appears when I do `sudo apt update` :

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:4 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease                    
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [169 kB]        
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [412 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [93,5 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [724 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [399 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [180 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [11,4 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages [13,4 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [110 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [16,5 kB]
Fetched 2 352 kB in 1s (2 345 kB/s)                                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
10 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Now `sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package virtualbox is a virtual package provided by:
  virtualbox-6.1 6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan
  virtualbox-6.0 6.0.24-139119~Ubuntu~eoan
You should explicitly select one to install.

Package virtualbox-ext-pack is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'virtualbox' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'virtualbox-ext-pack' has no installation candidate
```

Or when I do `sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-6.0 : Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: gcc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: make but it is not going to be installed or
                              build-essential but it is not going to be installed or
                              dpkg-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: binutils but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did

```
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

and

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib" | \
     sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

without any problems.

I hope everyone is having a good day :)

Answer (score 3):

**#Just Download a debian file:**

[https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961%7EUbuntu%7Eeoan_amd64.deb)

And install with :

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
```

**#If get's Any error**

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a repository to your system to download the package virtualbox needs:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
```

And then reinstall with the command:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1
```

It worked with me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib"
sudo apt-get update
```

If when doing apt-get update it appears:

> N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages'
> as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic
> InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

then:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

continue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install libpng16-16 libqt5core5a libqt5printsupport5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0 -y
```